MemoryStream object Throwing ReadTimeOut error (.NET 6.0)
I'm trying to create PDF in a .NET 6.0 application using the Itext7 library. This is a code snippet for the method. Now, while debugging I have noticed when creating the MemoryStream, the code is throwing a read timeout error. Specifically the error is:

ReadTimeOut = 'memorystream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Is there any way to fix it?
using System.IO;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;

public byte[] GeneratePdf(List<CustomObject> absenceList)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);

    // Initialize the PDF document
    var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

    // Initialize document layout
    var document = new Document(pdf);

    foreach (var absence in absenceList)
    {
        document.Add(new Paragraph($"Name: {absence. Name}"));
        document.Add(new Paragraph($"Type: {absence.Type}"));
        document.Add(new Paragraph($"Prop1: {absence.Prop1}"));
        document.Add(new Paragraph($"Prop2: {absence.Prop2}"));
        document.Add(new Paragraph($"Prop3: {absence.Prop3}"));
        document.Add(new Paragraph(" ")); // Add a blank line
    }

    document.Close();

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}


Check out this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67411657/10015628

The first thing I would check is if any created object is IDisposable, and if so, ensure they are disposed.

No there are no IDisposable objects created.

Hi @DireRaven, have you tried the solution given? Do you still need any assistance on this, let me know if you have any further concern.


I'm trying to create PDF in a .NET 6.0 application using the Itext7
library. This is a code snippet for the method. Now, while debugging I
have noticed when creating the MemoryStream, the code is throwing a
read timeout error. Specifically the error is:
ReadTimeOut = 'memorystream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type
'System.InvalidOperationException'

Well according to your error message, the "ReadTimeout" on a MemoryStream object in your code is unusual because MemoryStream doesn't have a ReadTimeout property.
When you access the MemoryStream object after closing the stream it would cause the exception becuase your MemoryStream has not been wrapped correctly.
In order to overcome the exception, you could wrapped the MemoryStream by using block. I have tried your scenario as following and its working as expected.
Wrapped memoryStream:
public class PdfGenerator
{
    public byte[] GeneratePdf(List<CustomObject> absenceList)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var writer = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);
            var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            var document = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf);


            foreach (var absence in absenceList)
            {
                document.Add(new Paragraph($"Name: {absence.Name}"));
                document.Add(new Paragraph($"Type: {absence.Type}"));
                document.Add(new Paragraph($"Prop1: {absence.Prop1}"));
                document.Add(new Paragraph($"Prop2: {absence.Prop2}"));
                document.Add(new Paragraph($"Prop3: {absence.Prop3}"));
                document.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
            }

            document.Close();

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

}

Demo Model:
public class CustomObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

Output:




Note: As you can see, the MemoryStream is created within a using statement, ensuring proper disposal of resources. Please refer to this official document for more example.
